Populate Timestamp Column in Postgres with NULLS
I've sqlalchemy ORM in Postgres with Timestamp column start_date,end_date and I've an existing excel data which I want to seed into the ORM Model.
For Few of the cases like new tasks there should not be any start_date, end_date as they are not yet approved. So I want to populate blank in those tasks but I'm getting error:
psycopg2.errors.InvalidDatetimeFormat: invalid input syntax for type timestamp: "NaT".
Is there any way we can populate Null values?
I've updated the ORM to make the columns nullable so that it accepts Null values but no luck, getting same error.

The error is pretty obvious the data is using NaT not NULL and NaT is not a valid timestamp value. You need to change those values to NULL in the data conversion process..
